# Prevent zsh from adding literal quotes to command that is run from bash script

Tags: bash, zsh

I have the bash script that will be installed on some coworker machines to prevent them from running potentially dangerous things in production.  For a command that starts with `dbt`, it will run the `dbt_safety_filter()` function.

The important portion is `command+=" --exclude tag:subject_to_qa"` which is what appends the safeguard to their command.

For some reason the output of this command is erroring because it is adding quotes around the appended section.  The debugging output is:

```
+ dbt_filter.sh:95 @dbt_safety_filter:10> dbt run --models bcnc_pqr_breast_cancer_screening ' --exclude tag:subject_to_qa'
```

The issue in particular is `dbt run --models bcnc_pqr_breast_cancer_screening ' --exclude tag:subject_to_qa'` where quotations are added to the last portion of the command, which is in turn breaking the command

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can i prevent the literal quotes from being added to the end of the command?

```
#!/bin/bash

function dbt_safety_filter {

  if [[ "$AWS_ENVIRONMENT" = "production" ]]; then  

      local command=("$@")
      command+=" --exclude tag:subject_to_qa"
        
      echo '\nProceeding on production on latest clean master.'
      echo '\n-----------------------------------------------'
      set -x 
      "`whence -p dbt`" $command
      set +x
    fi

}

alias dbt='dbt_safety_filter'
```

Comment: `unset -x` is invalid and should error. Are you sure you are running bash, and not zsh?

Comment: @KamilCuk it does error, you are right. But it prints my debug line before it.  Just haven't fixed it yet.  Will edit.

Comment: Try `command+=( --exclude tag:subject_to_qa )`

Comment: You would then need to use `"$(whence -p dbt)" "${command[@]}"`, unless you aren't actually using `bash`. (`whence` is a `zsh` command, and `zsh` lets you use `$foo` in place of `${foo[@]}`.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds several problems with the code.  Also, `whence` is not a Bash command.  The Bash equivalent is  `type`, but the best option for this in Bash is to use `command dbt "${command[@]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific question's answer is that you are adding  `--x y` to your argument list, which is of course an error, as you actually want two separate arguments `--x` `y`. To rectify it, use:

```
command+=( --exclude tag:subject_to_qa )
```

Your code might still have other problems, I haven't checked.